# How to display data from custom fields in my custom shortcode?

Tags: functions, custom-field, shortcode

This is the shortcode I have come up with, according to a tutorial on Dig WP (http://digwp.com/2010/01/custom-query-shortcode/) in order to display list of songs on specific albums.

```
[loop the_query="post_type=song&albumtype=enc&order=ASC&showposts=-1"]
```

Above is an example, using a custom taxonomy in order to achieve what I want. This returns a list item with the title and permalink of/to the song post type item.

However, I would also like to return data from a couple of custom fields associated to the song post type, such as "Duration". I tried to insert this the way I would in a template, but it did not return anything.

Where should I add what to the below code in order to display the value of the custom field next to the link?

```
function custom_query_shortcode($atts) {

// EXAMPLE USAGE:
// [loop the_query="showposts=100&post_type=page&post_parent=453"]

// Defaults
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  "the_query" => ''
), $atts));

// de-funkify query
$the_query = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $the_query);
$the_query = preg_replace('~&#0*([0-9]+);~e', 'chr(\\1)', $the_query);

// query is made               
query_posts($the_query);

// Reset and setup variables
$output = '';
$temp_title = '';
$temp_link = '';

// the loop
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  $temp_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
  $temp_link = get_permalink($post->ID);

  // output all findings - CUSTOMIZE TO YOUR LIKING
  $output .= "<li><a href='$temp_link'>$temp_title</a> I WANT MY CUSTOM FIELD VALUE HERE</li>";

endwhile; else:

  $output .= "nothing found.";

endif;

wp_reset_query();
return $output;

}
add_shortcode("loop", "custom_query_shortcode");
```

The above code is from my functions.php file, which is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend pointed out how to solve this. If anybody else runs into the same issue as me, this is the correct code.

```
// Custom shortcode, to query tracklistings.
function custom_query_shortcode($atts) {

// Defaults
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  "the_query" => ''
), $atts));

// de-funkify query
$the_query = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $the_query);
$the_query = preg_replace('~&#0*([0-9]+);~e', 'chr(\\1)', $the_query);

// query is made               
$query_posts = get_posts($the_query);

// Reset and setup variables
$output = '';

// the loop
if (!empty($query_posts)) {
    foreach($query_posts as &$post_object) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="'. get_permalink($post_object->ID) .'">'. $post_object->post_title .'</a> <span>'. get_post_meta($post_object->ID, 'Duration', true) .'</span></li>';
    }
}
return $output;
}
add_shortcode("loop", "custom_query_shortcode");
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to query your custom fields and return them with your shortcode:

```
// EXAMPLE USAGE:
// [loop the_query="showposts=100&post_type=page&post_parent=453"]
function custom_query_shortcode($atts) {
    // Defaults
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      "the_query" => ''
    ), $atts));

    // de-funkify query
    $the_query = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $the_query);
    $the_query = preg_replace('~&#0*([0-9]+);~e', 'chr(\\1)', $the_query);

    // query is made               
    query_posts($the_query);

    // Reset and setup variables
    $output = '';
    $temp_title = '';
    $temp_link = '';

    // the loop
    if (have_posts()){
        while (have_posts()){
            the_post();
            $temp_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
            $temp_link = get_permalink($post->ID);
            //get you custom fields
            $duration = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'duration', true );
            $other_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'other_custom_field_key', true );
            //add the custom field to the output var
            $output .= "<li><a href='$temp_link'>$temp_title</a> Duration: $duration, Other: $other_custom_field</li>";
        }
    }else{
        $output .= "nothing found.";
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("loop", "custom_query_shortcode");
```

Comment: This is what I did before I asked, but no value is returned, should I add anything to the shortcode itself?

Comment: NO, simply replace duration with the actual custom field key in the `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'duration', true );` call.

Comment: The name of the key IS 'duration', but nothing shows next to the link. :(

Comment: then something else is wrong in your setup... try adding `var_dump(get_post_custom($post->ID));`
inside the loop and see how and what data is stored.

Comment: Inside the loop in the actual template file used?

Comment: In the loop of the while in the shortcode.

Comment: I added it and nothing is happening.

Comment: Pardon. Here it is.

http://pastebin.com/4THCK3wK

Comment: Its 'Duration' in your end so change 'duration' to 'Duration'.

Comment: Done so one of the previous times and the output is now "Duration: Array"